# proc report to create table as it is

Tags: sas, proc-report

I am working on PROC REPORT. i want to crate table as it is

```
data have;
input A B $ C E F G I K L M N;
datalines;
1 japan 190 46 15 0 0 0 0 0 1
2 us 152 39 47 86 0 0 0 0 1
3 aus 50 6 36 41 0 0 0 0 1
;
proc report data=have;
column ("A" ("" A)) ("B" ("" B)) ("C" ("" C)) ("D" (("E" E) ("F" F))) ("G" ("" G))
("H" ("I" I) ('J' K L M) ("N" N));
define A / "" display;
define B / "" display;
define C / "" display;
define E / "" display;
define F / "" display;
define G / "" display;
define I / "" display;
define K / display;
define L / display;
define M / display;
define N / "" display;
run;
```

i want this type of table structure

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mBtGC.png)

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to get PROC REPORT to do this. An alternative approach is given in [this paper](https://support.sas.com/resources/papers/proceedings13/040-2013.pdf), which shows how to use the SAS Report Writing Interface to achieve this result in a data step.

(It is not compatible with SAS Report output but works for HTML, PDF etc.)

For your example, the code would be:

```
data _null_;
    set have end=done;
     * first start the table and create the header;
     if _n_ eq 1 then do;
         declare odsout t(); * create a report writing interface object named t;

         t.table_start(); * start the table;
         t.head_start(); * start the header (so that these items get the default header style);
            * in this case the header is 3 rows in height. the ROWSPAN and COLSPAN items 
                control the size of each cell in the header;
             t.row_start();
                 t.format_cell(text: 'A', rowspan:3);
                 t.format_cell(text: 'B', rowspan:3);
                 t.format_cell(text: 'C', rowspan:3);
                 t.format_cell(text: 'D', rowspan:2, colspan:2);
                 t.format_cell(text: 'G', rowspan:3);
                 t.format_cell(text: 'H', colspan:5);
             t.row_end();

             t.row_start();
                 t.format_cell(text: 'I', rowspan:2);
                 t.format_cell(text: 'J', colspan:3);
                 t.format_cell(text: 'N', rowspan:2);
             t.row_end();

             t.row_start();
                 t.format_cell(text:'E');
                 t.format_cell(text:'F');
                 t.format_cell(text:'K');
                 t.format_cell(text:'L');
                 t.format_cell(text:'M');
             t.row_end();
         t.head_end();
     end;

     * the rest of the cells are all simply data values;
     t.row_start();
         t.format_cell(text: A);
         t.format_cell(text: B);
         t.format_cell(text: C);
         t.format_cell(text: E);
         t.format_cell(text: F);
         t.format_cell(text: G);
         t.format_cell(text: I);
         t.format_cell(text: K);
         t.format_cell(text: L);
         t.format_cell(text: M);
         t.format_cell(text: N);
     t.row_end();

     if done then t.table_end();
run;
```